# csharp code to remove all extraneous microsoft html formatting

Tags: html, ms-word, tinymce

is there any way to programatically remove all microsoft html formatting that gets put on and simply render it as regular html.

i want to remove all the extra tags as i am trying to load it into tinymce but tinymce doesn't seem to be able to render it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've used the regular expressions from these articles:

- http://tim.mackey.ie/CleanWordHTMLUsingRegularExpressions.aspx
- [How do I filter all HTML tags except a certain whitelist?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307013/how-do-i-filter-all-html-tags-except-a-certain-whitelist)

In my case I wanted to restrict everyone down to a small whitelist of tags.  Especially those who paste from Word. TinyMCE has a property "valid_elements" which does exactly this.