# Regex paterns to remove word formatting

Tags: c#, html, regex

I am having a problem using regex patterns to replace items in HTML markup. The values that I am trying to replace are these:

```
<!--[if mso 9]-->
<style>
 p.MsoNormal<br />
 {margin-left:18.75pt;}<br />
</style>
<!--[endif]-->
```

and

```
class="MsoNormal"
```

I am not the best at using Regex the patterns that I have come up with so far are:

1. `<!--(.*?)-->`
2. `class=\"msonormal\"`
3. `class=\"MsoNormal\"`

Item 1 removes anything that starts with `<!--` and ends with `-->` but it only does it once it doesn't remove all instances.

I don't think items 2 and 3 are working at all.

I found some of this information for the patterns here:

[is there a Way to strip all Unnecessary MS Word Formatting from FCKEditor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1349837/is-there-a-way-to-strip-all-unnecessary-ms-word-formatting-from-fckeditor)

The full listing of text that I want to remove is this:

```
    <!--[if !mso]><style>v\:* {behavior:url(#default#VML);}
o\:* {behavior:url(#default#VML);}
w\:* {behavior:url(#default#VML);}
.shape {behavior:url(#default#VML);}
</style><![endif]-->
<title>Blank</title>
<style>
    <!--
/* Font Definitions */
@font-face
    {font-family:Helvetica;
    panose-1:2 11 6 4 2 2 2 2 2 4;}
@font-face
    {font-family:"Cambria Math";
    panose-1:2 4 5 3 5 4 6 3 2 4;}
@font-face
    {font-family:Calibri;
    panose-1:2 15 5 2 2 2 4 3 2 4;}
@font-face
    {font-family:Tahoma;
    panose-1:2 11 6 4 3 5 4 4 2 4;}
@font-face
    {font-family:"Arial Black";
    panose-1:2 11 10 4 2 1 2 2 2 4;}
@font-face
    {font-family:"Palatino Linotype";
    panose-1:2 4 5 2 5 5 5 3 3 4;}
@font-face
    {font-family:"Trebuchet MS";
    panose-1:2 11 6 3 2 2 2 2 2 4;}
@font-face
    {font-family:"Matura MT Script Capitals";
    panose-1:3 2 8 2 6 6 2 7 2 2;}
/* Style Definitions */
p.MsoNormal, li.MsoNormal, div.MsoNormal
    {margin-top:0in;
    margin-right:0in;
    mso-margin-bottom-alt:auto;
    margin-left:0in;
    font-size:10.0pt;
    font-family:"Helvetica","sans-serif";
    color:#FFFFCC;
    mso-believe-normal-left:yes;}
a:link, span.MsoHyperlink
    {mso-style-priority:99;
    color:blue;
    text-decoration:underline;}
a:visited, span.MsoHyperlinkFollowed
    {mso-style-priority:99;
    color:purple;
    text-decoration:underline;}
p
    {mso-style-priority:99;
    mso-margin-top-alt:auto;
    margin-right:0in;
    mso-margin-bottom-alt:auto;
    margin-left:0in;
    font-size:12.0pt;
    font-family:"Times New Roman","serif";}
p.MsoAcetate, li.MsoAcetate, div.MsoAcetate
    {mso-style-priority:99;
    mso-style-link:"Balloon Text Char";
    margin-top:0in;
    margin-right:0in;
    mso-margin-bottom-alt:auto;
    margin-left:0in;
    font-size:8.0pt;
    font-family:"Tahoma","sans-serif";
    color:#FFFFCC;}
p.MsoNoSpacing, li.MsoNoSpacing, div.MsoNoSpacing
    {mso-style-priority:1;
    margin:0in;
    margin-bottom:.0001pt;
    font-size:12.0pt;
    font-family:"Times New Roman","serif";}
span.BalloonTextChar
    {mso-style-name:"Balloon Text Char";
    mso-style-priority:99;
    mso-style-link:"Balloon Text";
    font-family:"Tahoma","sans-serif";
    color:#FFFFCC;}
span.EmailStyle21
    {mso-style-type:personal;
    font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";
    color:black;}
span.EmailStyle22
    {mso-style-type:personal;
    font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";
    color:#0F243E;}
span.EmailStyle23
    {mso-style-type:personal;
    font-family:"Calibri","sans-serif";
    color:#1F497D;}
span.EmailStyle24
    {mso-style-type:personal;
    font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";
    color:#0F243E;}
span.EmailStyle25
    {mso-style-type:personal;
    font-family:"Calibri","sans-serif";
    color:#1F497D;}
span.EmailStyle26
    {mso-style-type:personal;
    font-family:"Calibri","sans-serif";
    color:#1F497D;}
span.EmailStyle27
    {mso-style-type:personal;
    font-family:"Calibri","sans-serif";
    color:#1F497D;}
span.EmailStyle28
    {mso-style-type:personal;
    font-family:"Calibri","sans-serif";
    color:#1F497D;}
span.EmailStyle29
    {mso-style-type:personal;
    font-family:"Calibri","sans-serif";
    color:windowtext;}
span.EmailStyle30
    {mso-style-type:personal;
    font-family:"Calibri","sans-serif";
    color:#1F497D;}
span.EmailStyle31
    {mso-style-type:personal;
    font-family:"Calibri","sans-serif";
    color:#1F497D;}
span.EmailStyle33
    {mso-style-type:personal-reply;
    font-family:"Calibri","sans-serif";
    color:#1F497D;}
.MsoChpDefault
    {mso-style-type:export-only;
    font-size:10.0pt;}
@page WordSection1
    {size:8.5in 11.0in;
    margin:1.0in 1.0in 1.0in 1.0in;}
div.WordSection1
    {page:WordSection1;}
-->
</style>
<!--[if mso 9]-->
<style>
    p.MsoNormal
    {margin-left:18.75pt;}
</style>
<!--[endif]--><!--[if gte mso 9]>
<o:shapedefaults v:ext="edit" spidmax="1026" />
<![endif]--><!--[if gte mso 9]>


<p class="MsoNormal"><span style="font-size: 11pt; font-family: Calibri, sans-serif; color: #1f497d;"><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></span></p>
<p class="MsoNormal"><span style="font-size: 11pt; font-family: Calibri, sans-serif; color: #1f497d;"><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></span></p>
<p class="MsoNormal"><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this pattern for catching the first group of items:

```
\<\!\-\-\[i[\w\s\p{P}\p{S}]+if\]\-\-\>
```

The point is to avoid `.*` as far as possible for it will eat the whole input string hence the ending criteria is not matched.

For the 2nd and 3rd, you only need to escape the `=` sign as in `\=`. They would be fine, however try the following pattern to catch other `Mso*` classes too:

```
class\=\"Mso[^\"]+\"
```

Comment: Thanks Sina, the first pattern works perfectly in all of my tests thus far but I can't get the second pattern to work. Thanks for you help.

Comment: @cjohns hmm..., I'm testing the second pattern against your sample input above and it works fine. I'm using [RegexHero](http://regexhero.net/tester/) for my online testing, which is a .NET based regex engine.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, when you want a Regexp to run over each possible instance, you need to add the "g" operator, meaning global. In C#, what you usually do is use [Regexp.matches()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.matches.aspx) to find every instance and then operate on them.

As for the class="MsoNormal", I can't find any instance of that in your text. Are you sure you're searching for the correct pattern?

Comment: thanks for pointing out the missing class="MsoNormal" tag. I just added that at the bottom. I am trying the "g" operator now and looking at that link you added.

Comment: Your second regexp works in Ruby at least. Are you sure you're declaring it correctly in C#? Remember than \ has a special meaning inside of strings, so maybe you need to double escape it, something like class=\\"MsoNormal\\"