# Need Help to make this regex for my whiteList

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I am using a rich html editor and I want to make a whitelist of the stuff that should be allowed in.

I heard that you should use a whitelist instead of black list since it is easier to do then trying to then making a blacklist.

I even seen some examples where people could hide the script tag in a css style part.

So this is a sample of what the editor generates

```
<span _moz_dirty="" style="font-weight: bold;">
aaaaaaaaaaaa
<br _moz_dirty=""/>
ffffffffffff
<br _moz_dirty=""/>
<span _moz_dirty="" style="text-decoration: underline;">
fffffffff
<br _moz_dirty=""/>
</span>
<span _moz_dirty="" style="text-decoration: line-through;">
aaaaaaaaaa
<br _moz_dirty=""/>
<sub _moz_dirty="">
</sub>
<sup _moz_dirty="">ggg</sup>
<sub _moz_dirty="">
</sub>
</span>
</span>
<ol _moz_dirty="">
<li _moz_dirty="">1333</li>
<li _moz_dirty="">ff</li>
</ol>
<ul _moz_dirty="">
<li _moz_dirty="">ggg</li>
<li _moz_dirty="">ff</li>
</ul>
<div _moz_dirty="" style="margin-left: 40px;">
ffffff
<br _moz_dirty=""/>
</div>
fff
<br _moz_dirty=""/>
<br _moz_dirty=""/>
<a _moz_dirty="" href="http://">ffff</a>
<br _moz_dirty="" type="_moz"/>
<span _moz_dirty="" style="font-weight: bold;">
<span _moz_dirty="" style="text-decoration: underline;"/>
</span>
```

So I guess a my white list would be allows these tags with the right class names

```
<span>
style - font-weight: bold, text-decoration: underline, margin-left, margin-right
<br />
<a>
<ol>
<ul>
<li>
```

So I am trying to make a regex that I can pop into my C# code to check for only these tags.

So I tried to start with the style stuff

```
style="[^font\-style|weight]+\s*:\s*[bold|italic]+\s*;\s*"
```

but it does not work. I tried to change things around from the sample I gave you but nothing shows up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using square brackets, which create a character class; you should instead use parenthesis to indicate an alternative, i.e.

```
font-(style|weight)
```

The + is redundant (you don't want one **or more**, right?).
I think your regexs should be something like

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"font-(style|weight)\s*:\s*(bold|italic)\s*;\s*");
```

Another thing: '^' indicates beginning of line/string, so you should remove it.

Comment: You regex is spot on.  I'm just mincing here.  Not that you are capturing, but it is good to keep in mind that () = capturing group. use (?:) for a non capturing group.  (?:style|weight)  You can also use the implicit groups option.

Answer (score 1):

Siilar to this question:  [How do I filter all HTML tags except a certain whitelist?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307013/how-do-i-filter-all-html-tags-except-a-certain-whitelist)

Answer (score 0):

escape your backslashes?

Comment: Rather put an @ before the string. Regexes aren't easy to read already; but regexes with escaped backslashes are are pain to read.

Comment: Good point.  You should use the @ sign.  It's not so fun to read "\\s".