# regex exclude certain tags

Tags: javascript, regex

just need a quick help for solving this problem.

I want to strip all html tags out of a string except the tags from a whitelist(variable).

My code so far:

```
whitelist = 'p|br|ul|li|strike|em|strong|a', 
reqExp = new RegExp('<\/?[^>|' + whitelist + ']+\/?>');
```

The problem is now it works more or less fine but also not removing for example `b` because it matches the `b` from the `br` out of the whitelist.

I tried different approaches but dont find the right solution.
How can i tell the regex to do something like `/.WITHOUT(smth)/` (therefore: match all expect everything following).

Comment: You'd be better off using a callback for the replacement and examining the tag matched.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: @alex: yes could be a solution but fine with the regex of the accepted answer

Comment: @ahm: yes i saw this post but in my case im fine with the answer - is not a massive dangerous/very important application. thx anyway

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this regex:-

```
<(?!/?(p|br|ul|li|strike|em|strong|a)(>|\s))[^<]+?>
```

### [LIVE DEMO](http://regexr.com?30npe)

For more information, refer to **[my earlier answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9553958/500725)**, which fullfill your requirement.

Comment: thank you. this works for me as it should. also nice regexonline-testing engine.