# regex check certain tags

Tags: javascript, regex, typescript, tags

I want to check if certain tags are included in the passed string value or not excluding `a` and `p` tags.

For the sample input:

```
<p><a href="fdssadfafads" target="_blank">aaa<span>dddd</span></a>bbb</p><span>ccc</span>
```

The result should be:

```
false
```

Because the input contains `span` tags.

Now, I have tried some [regexp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10267871/regex-exclude-certain-tags) like this:

```
<(?!/?(p|a)(>|\s))[^<]+?>
```

But it didn't work for me.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You have not explained what you are trying to achieve here... Your problem is not clear at all...

Comment: If you want to match the `<span>` tag, simply escape the slash character in your original regex:

[`<(?!\/?(p|a)(>|\s))[^<]+?>`](https://regex101.com/r/MP6jmM/1)

Comment: So basically, you want to result in `true` if the input does not contain `<span>...</span>`, right?

Answer (score 1):

You could try this regex:

```
(?<=<span>)(?:.*?)(?=<\/span>)
```

Like so:

```js
regex = "(?<=<span>)(?:.*?)(?=<\/span>)";

str = "<p><a href=\"fdssadfafads\" target=\"_blank\">aaa<span>dddd</span></a>bbb</p><span>ccc</span>";
str2 = "There is no tag"

found = str.search(regex)==-1?false:true;
found2 = str2.search(regex)==-1?false:true;

document.write("'span' tags found - "+found);
document.write(" and 'span' tags found - "+found2);
```

## Explanation -

`(?<=<span>)` - A positive look-behind to tell the regex system to match the text if it is preceded by `<span>`
`(?:.*?)` - A non-capturing group that tells the system that there may be zero or more characters between the opening and closing `span` tags
`(?=<\/span>)` - A positive look-ahead that ensures that the match is followed by a `</span>` tag

`found = str.search(regex)==-1?false:true;` is a ternary operator - if the search for the regex results in `-1` (not found) then result stores `false`

**Note -** The above code works fine when searching for the presence of opening and closing span tags in the input, which is what I assume the OP desires.
However, the question being unclear, certain desired specifications may not be met.

Answer (score 0):

If it is an option to do this without regex (because it is not recommended to [parse html with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)), you could use a [DOMParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) and [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) to get all the elements in the body. Then check if there is an element which is not an `a` or `p`.

```js
let elms = ['p', 'a'];
let htmlInvalid = `<p><a href="fdssadfafads" target="_blank">aaa<span>dddd</span></a>bbb</p><span>ccc</span>`;
let htmlValid = `<p><a href="fdssadfafads" target="_blank">aaa`;

function isHtmlValid(strHtml, allowedElements) {
  let parser = new DOMParser();
  let doc = parser.parseFromString(strHtml, "text/html");
  let elements = doc.querySelectorAll('body *');
  for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; ++i) {
    if (allowedElements.indexOf(elements[i].nodeName.toLowerCase()) < 0) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}

console.log(isHtmlValid(htmlInvalid, elms));
console.log(isHtmlValid(htmlValid, elms));
```