# Regx for Identify HTML tag started but not closed

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

I have requirement where I have to Identify 2 point.

1. Replace all tag that is having closed tag but exculding few tags Like `<a></a>, <p></p>, <i></i>`.
   For this I did lots of R&D but not able to find exact solution.
   My final finding regx : `(?!<p|a|i|>)(?<opentag><(?!/)[^>]*[^/]>)`

But this is also finding tag that not having closing tag Like `<abc>`

**NOTE:** In this I want to replace start and close tag with space.

2. If we have Tag that not having closing tag then I want to remove only special symbol not whole tag. `<abc>` should be `abc`

**Example:**

**Input String:**

```
   <br />
   <ul id="matchMe" type="square">
      <li>stuff...</li>
      <li>more stuff</li>
      <li>
          <div>
               <span>still more</span>
               <ul>
                    <li>Another &gt;ul&lt;, oh my!</li>
                    <li>...</li>
               </ul>
          </div>
      </li>
   </ul>
<p>....</p>
<p class="hhh">....</p>

<customTag1> Hello <CustomTag2>
```

**Output String:**

```
      stuff...
      more stuff


               still more

                    Another &gt;ul&lt;, oh my!
                    ...




<p>....</p>
<p class="hhh">....</p>

customTag1 Hello CustomTag2
```

In this example I do not want to do anything with `p` tag but all other tag that having self closing tag or closing tag should be replace with blank.
`customTag1` and `CustomTag2` both tags are custom and it's looking like HTML start tag but do not having end tag. For these tag I just want to remove `<,>` symbol only.

Few answer helped here but not fully
https://stackoverflow.com/a/7564061/4813631
https://stackoverflow.com/a/10267932/4813631

Thanks

Comment: Could you give us an example of the initial string and the desired output to be more clear your question? I mean, something like "this is my html and that is my desired output"

Comment: @Pablo I added example. I hope example will enough to understand my issue.

Answer (score 0):

It should works:

```js
let html = `<br />
<ul id="matchMe" type="square">
   <li>stuff...</li>
   <li>more stuff</li>
   <li>
       <div>
            <span>still more</span>
            <ul>
                 <li>Another &gt;ul&lt;, oh my!</li>
                 <li>...</li>
            </ul>
       </div>
   </li>
</ul>
<p>....</p>
<p class="hhh">....</p>

<customTag1> Hello <CustomTag2>
`
let allInitialsTags = html.match(/<([a-zA-Z\d]*(?=\s)*(?!\/))/g)
allInitialsTags = allInitialsTags.map(el=>el.replace("<",''))
let allEndTags = html.match(/(<\/[a-zA-Z\d]*\s*)/g)
allEndTags = allEndTags.map(el=>el.replace("</",''))
const tagWithNotClosingTag = []
allInitialsTags.forEach(el=>{
     if(!allEndTags.includes(el)){
          tagWithNotClosingTag.push(el)
     }
})
tagWithNotClosingTag.forEach(el=> {
     html = html.replace(RegExp(`<${el}>`,'g'),`${el}`)
})

const result = html.replace(/<[^(p|a|i)]?[^(\/p|\/a)?][^>]*>/g,"")
console.log(result)
```