# Rails Storing text body that's written with a rich text editor in HTML format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rich-text-editor, text-formatting

Is it safe and conventional to store the html text input written with a javascript text editor into my database?

Assume I'm using ckeditor for users to input their articles in my application. Articles look fine when you view it from the client side, but when you query it from the database, it's too messy.

For example, the text body will be stored like below:

```
<p class="MsoListParagraph" style="margin-left:56.0pt;mso-para-margin-left:0gd;
text-indent:-18.0pt;mso-list:l3 level1 lfo1"><!--[if !supportLists]--><span lang="EN-US" style="font-size: 12pt; font-family: 'Times New Roman';">-<span style="font-size: 12pt; line-height: normal;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
</span></span><!--[endif]--><span lang="EN-US" style="font-size: 12pt; font-family: 'Times New Roman';">Natural selection is a process that individuals
have some heritable characteristics to survive and reproduce at a higher rate
compare to other individuals. Natural selection increases the match between
organisms and environments. Furthermore, as an environment changes or
individuals move to a new place, natural selection may effect of adaptation to
these new conditions by giving rise to new species in the process. Natural
selection can only increase or decrease heritable traits.&nbsp; <u><o:p></o:p></u></span></p>
```

The body is then rendered like `@article.body.html_safe`

Is there a better way to handle this matter?

Answer (score 0):

If the database doesn't need to know the internals of the text, its fine to store it like this, effectively treating it as an opaque blob.

The bigger issue is security in the web browser when someone views the item.  You need to be vary careful to validate the input because otherwise someone could store a bit of javascript in the document, and then that javascript would run on the browser of anyone viewing that article.

See answers like the ones on here: [filtering tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307013/how-do-i-filter-all-html-tags-except-a-certain-whitelist)