# HTML to RTF to HTML = HTML Without scripts?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, xss

I'd like to implement a [**WYSIWYG**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WYSIWYG) `HTML` editor in my web application. I looked at the **Codeplex AntiXSS** by Microsoft for Crosssite Scripting protection, and the feedback seems really bad.

The alternative I have in mind is converting the input from the editor to `RTF` and then back to `HTML` and only then ship it to the database so it can be served later. I understand that this is an incredibly inefficient method, but the question is if that way I can guarantee no scripts at all. or in other words, can this provide me a complete XSS protection?

Comment: Why not use something like [TinyMCE](http://www.tinymce.com/) ?

Comment: As far as I understandt TinyMCE is the client side editor, and seems to be a good one.  but I'm talking about the server side, dose TinyMCE provides any server side xss protection?

Comment: You can sanitize the incoming HTML just to be 100%. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/307013/how-do-i-filter-all-html-tags-except-a-certain-whitelist